# Add column to dataframe by iterating over rows using fuzzy match function

Tags: function, for-loop, pattern-matching, fuzzy, difflib

I want to create a new column in a pandas data frame by applying fuzzy match to an existing column. I'm able to successfully test the match but it errors out when I try to use the function to add resulting values to a new column.

Code runs in test run:

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import get_close_matches

#Create df of 2 columns
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['dog.Ronaldo','dog.Benjamin','cat.Genevieve', 'dog.GermanShepherd', 'cat.Tom'], "B": ['dog.Ron', 'dog.Gen', 'dog.Benjamin', 'cat.Tim', None]})

#List to test matching based on col B
patterns = ['dog.Ron', 'dog.Gen', 'dog.Benjamin', 'cat.Tim', None]

#Iterate over rows in df to isolate closest match from test_lst/col B and match score. If no match, print error message
for row in df.iloc[:,0]:
  try:
    best_tbl_match = get_close_matches(
      row, 
      patterns, 
      n=1
    )[0]
    print(row, ';', best_tbl_match,  ';', difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, row, best_tbl_match).ratio(), '>')
  except Exception:
    #failure comment
    run_comment = f'{row}; No Match ; 0'
    print(run_comment)
```

However, when I write this as a function and try to add resulting values to a new column in the df, it produces the wrong results.

Desired result - excluded col B as I will drop it.

[image]

```
for row in df.iloc[:,0]:
  try:
    df['match'] = best_match(row)
    df['score'] = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, row, best_tbl_match).ratio()
    #print(row, ',', best_tbl_match,',',  difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, row, best_tbl_match).ratio())
  except Exception:
    #failure comment
    df['match'] = 'No match'
    df['score'] = 0
```

Also tried the apply syntax which isn't functioning either:

```
for row in df.iloc[:,0]:
  try:
    df['match2'] = df.A.apply(best_match)
  except Exception:
    #print(row, 'fail')
    print("exception")
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What results were you expecting?

Comment: Just posted an image of the results I wanted. It's pretty much the results from the functioning code, but in a dataframe so I can pop it into an excel without additional manual manipulation.